# Search in Json Array in MySql Table

Tags: mysql, json

I am storing the json array in the mysql field called member_details,

```
[{"religion":null,"caste":["2","3","4"],"sub_caste":["0","1","2"],"family_value":null,"family_status":null}]
```

Now, I want to search for the members who are having caste of 3. Some times I need to search for `sub_caste 2`.

How can i achieve that?

I have tried to use json_contains but it is giving me empty results

```
select * from member where json_contains('member_details', '{"caste" : "2"}')
```

but it gives empty result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(member_details->"$[0].caste", 'one', '3') IS NOT NULL;
```

The syntax `member_details->"$[0].caste` first accesses the first (and only) JSON element in the outer array, using `[0]`.  Then, it accesses the `caste` key, using `.caste`.  Finally, `JSON_SEARCH` checks if the value 3 occurs within the caste array.

If you needed to search for `sub_caste` 2 then you could use similar logic.

Answer (score 0):

- `select * from member where JSON_EXTRACT(caste, "2");`

Can you please try this query for getting values from DB.
[Reference Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html)

I hope this helps you.